# Pandas: join datetime columns with another dataframe (performance)

Tags: pandas, performance

I have a DataFrame `main_df` with 10 datetime columns (`d_0 ... d_9`). For some rows I have less than 10 dates so I pad `d0 .. d_X` with `NaT`.

```
        id                 d_0                 d_1                 d_2                 d_3                d_4                  d_5                 d_6                 d_7                 d_8                d_9
530124   4 2019-05-20 13:49:24 2019-05-29 11:06:30 2019-06-11 19:04:40 2019-06-18 19:40:37 2019-07-09 10:17:05 2019-07-18 17:39:30 2019-08-02 12:35:13 2019-08-13 10:09:59 2019-08-17 16:38:45 2019-08-26 12:07:28
627023   8                 NaT                 NaT                 NaT 2018-01-03 17:14:42 2018-01-15 16:40:22 2018-01-18 17:28:03 2018-04-23 12:00:27 2018-05-24 17:49:01 2018-06-07 16:41:15 2018-07-22 15:22:48
470303   6                 NaT                 NaT                 NaT                 NaT                 NaT                 NaT 2017-06-19 14:23:57 2017-10-04 14:25:21 2017-10-11 15:38:28 2017-12-28 18:39:00
```

I also have a dict (`date_dfs`) that maps each value of `id` to a DataFrame that holds values for all the dates. All these dataframes have a `DatetimeIndex` and 3 columns with values for each possible date. My goal is to do a join between `main_df` and the corresponding `date_df`. So for a specific row in `main_df` I want to get a (10, 3) shape array. I want to do this for every row in `main_df` to get a `(n, 10, 3)` shape array where `n = len(main_df)`.

Currently, I am doing this row by row, and because my `main_df` has around 500k rows this takes a painfully long time. My Code so far is something like this:

```py
dt_cols = [f'd_{i}' for i in range(10)]
result = []

for seq_idx in range(len(main_df)):
    seq = main_df.iloc[seq_idx]
    seq_dt_cols = seq[dt_cols]

    # Necessary because `seq_dt_cols` has type `object`
    date_series = pd.to_datetime(seq_dt_cols[seq.pad_end:], infer_datetime_format=True)
    seq_dates = date_series.dt.date - pd.DateOffset(1)

    # pad missing values with -1
    pad = np.full(shape=(seq.pad_end, 3), fill_value=-1, dtype=np.float32)

    date_vals = self.date_dfs[seq.id].loc[seq_dates].values.astype(np.float32)
    result.append(np.concatenate((pad, date_vals)))

return np.stack(result)
```

I think the call to `pd.to_datetime` for each row is a big part of what makes this so slow, but I have to do it, since Pandas doesn't convert the Series to `datetime`, even though all the columns have type `datetime`.

Can I make this faster somehow ?

Comment: You have `return` but no `def` statement

Comment: That's not particularly relevant here. I just wanted to illustrate what the end goal is.